# How can I prevent rufus-scheduler from accruing a backlog of tasks when my computer is in standby?

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I recently started running a Dashing application locally on my laptop. Rufus-scheduler handles the scheduling of the jobs that update the dashboard. I have a job scheduled to run every minute. The job spawns another process and captures the output. When I shut the lid of my laptop for a few hours, and open the lid again, I can barely use the laptop, because hundreds of processes have started up and consumed all my RAM and several gigabytes of swap. They eventually finish over the next several minutes, and I can resume using my laptop normally.

How can I configure my jobs to not be scheduled when the computer is sleeping? Or is there a better way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple solutions.

a) with rufus-scheduler 2.x, use :discard_past => true (https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/two/README.rdoc#every-jobs-and-first_at--first_in last sentence)

b) don't use dashing on a laptop

c) use rufus-scheduler 3.x, which, by default, doesn't schedule in the past

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [according to the rufus-scheduler 2.0.x documentation](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/blob/two/README.rdoc), I can use `scheduler.cron` (maybe in combination with `blocking => true` option) instead of `scheduler.every` so that missed jobs won't fire in the future once the scheduler process is free.